# Is there a way to disallow a certain command or trigger an "are you sure" prompt (macOS)?

Tags: macos, command-line

I'd like to rig a particular command up with a failsafe such that it either can't be used at all, or at least there's an "are you sure" prompt. If I can do it in a particular directory, great, and if it's global I can live with that (better if it's the prompt though).

I really don't mind a hacky way. It doesn't have to be clean :)

**My specific context**

I'm using the [clasp](https://github.com/google/clasp/) CLI to push/pull code between my local machine and google apps script.

I actually do a lot of work on the google apps script console for easier autocomplete, and I pull to my local machine as a backup at the end of a session using `clasp pull`. At this point, an accidental `clasp push` could destroy hours of work in one fell swoop. Unlike `git` there's no add/commit workflow beforehand so the mistake is really easy to make.

Comment: The easiest way would be to go to the path of clasp push and change the permissions for your user.

Comment: Use a function or alias?